# Debugging javascript in runtime with webstorm

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug an html file with js injected itself, so I set some breakpoints inside the js part and when I run it it debugs at the first run, but then when I want to using the console (in Chrome) it stops debug and the breakpoints of course are not affected.

when I get inside the Chrome's console as I said it stops debug and shows me the following message: `Disconnected (tab was closed or Web Inspector was opened or explicitly detached via Chrome info bar).` disconnected means stops debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome bug, please vote for http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129539